# How to make a macro like \parbox with a style of spread align

Tags: minipage, parbox

I'd like to construct a macro like `\parbox`, but with a style of spread align, as the option `[s]` in `\makebox`. 
That is to say, when the width of text is less than the defined width(only one line of text), the text will typeset spread align. If the width of text is longer than defined width, it behaves just as \parbox.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{...}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\newparbox[3][]{...}
|\newparbox{8em}{AB AB}|\par
|\newparbox[t]{8em}{AB AB AB AB AB AB AB}|
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check if the width of the argument is bigger than the given width with `\ifdim`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newparbox[3][]{%
    \settowidth\@tempdima{#3}
    \ifdim\@tempdima>#2\relax
        \parbox[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    \else
        \makebox[#2][s]{#3}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

|\newparbox{8em}{AB AB}|\par
|\newparbox[t]{8em}{AB AB AB AB AB AB AB}|
\end{document}
```

Edit: LaTeX version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newparbox[3][]{%
    \settowidth\@tempdima{#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\@tempdima > #2}}{\parbox[#1]{#2}{#3}}{\makebox[#2][s]{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

|\newparbox{8em}{AB AB}|\par
|\newparbox[t]{8em}{AB AB AB AB AB AB AB}|
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried with this \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\widthof{#3} < #2}} (\usepackage{ifthen,calc}, but it fails to compile. Wht's wrong with this? And could you provide with a Latex version of your code?

Comment: @lyl You can't use `\widthof` in the argument of `\lengthtest`.

Comment: The reason why `\widthof` is used is, I don't want introduce a new length variable. Can I get this? And why `\widthof` can not be used in `\lengthtest`?

Comment: @lyl You can't, that's all: TeX can't perform assignments in the middle of the evaluation of a conditional.

Comment: If there are ``\\`` in #3, how to handle it to get exactly the same effect above. I mean, not just the first line, every line(delimited by ``\\``), if the length of a certain line is shorter than #2, then spread align it, otherwise, typeset like `\parbox`