# How to remove the last line-feed raised by \foreach

Tags: minipage, parbox

As the following example showes, there are an extra line-feed which is not needed. Is there a way to eliminate?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\mylist{str1,str2,str3}

\framebox{
  \parbox{4em}{%
    \foreach \x in \mylist {%
      \makebox[4em][s]{\x}\\%
    }%
  }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you issue a `\\` at the end of each line. You can avoid it e.g. with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\mylist{str1,str2,str3}

\framebox{
  \parbox{4em}{%
    \foreach \X [count=\Y]in \mylist {%
      \ifnum\Y=1
        \makebox[4em][s]{\X}
      \else 
        \\ \makebox[4em][s]{\X}%
      \fi
    }%
  }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A simple and exactly what I want solution! Thank you!

Comment: @lyl You're welcome!

Comment: Normally, `\parbox` has not the ability to spread align. In this question, we just achieve it by manually add ``\\`` to ensure spread align only for those lengh shorter than defined width. I wonder if there are solutions to spread align text in \parbox `autometically`?

Comment: @lyl What do you mean by "spread align"? Something like justify? (BTW, will go hibernate now.)

Comment: Yes, just like the option`[s]` in `\makebox`. Ok, I'll post another question to illustrate my meaning. Have a nice evening!

Answer (score 6):

A `listofitems` alternative...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\readlist*\mylist{str1,str2,str3}
\framebox{%
  \parbox{4em}{%
    \foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
      \makebox[4em][l]{\x}%
      \ifnum\xcnt<\mylistlen\relax\\\fi%
    }%
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or switch the test order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\readlist*\mylist{str1,str2,str3}
\framebox{%
  \parbox{4em}{%
    \foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
      \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax\else\\\fi%
      \makebox[4em][l]{\x}%
    }%
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### With a conditionnal (minimum code text)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\mylist{str1,str2,str3}
\framebox{
  \parbox{4em}{%
    \foreach \x[count=\n] in \mylist {%
      \ifnum \n >1 \\ \fi
      \makebox[4em][s]{\x}%
    }%
  }
}

\end{document}
```

#### With an array (just for the fun of it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\mylist{str1,str2,str3}
\def\before{{"\noexpand\\",{}}}
\framebox{
  \parbox{4em}{%
    \foreach \x[count=\n from 0] in \mylist {%
      \pgfmathparse{\before[!\n]}\pgfmathresult
      \makebox[4em][s]{\x}%
    }%
  }
}

\end{document}
```

#### Without any conditional ....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\mylist{str2,str3}

\framebox{
  \parbox{4em}{%
   str1
    \foreach \x in \mylist {%
      \\\makebox[4em][s]{\x}%
    }%
  }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also a fine idea. Thank you. Yet I'm afraid I can't take the first string out of my list.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `\before[!\n]'. why "[ ]" and what the meaning of "!n"?

Comment: I use a array as described on page 999 of the tikz 3.1 manual

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll go through it.

Answer (score 1):

With the general purpose macro suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475291/4427 (slightly modified):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% a general purpose macro for defining other macros
% \makemultiargument* will do a one step expansion of the second argument
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemultiargument}{smmmmm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \projetmbc_multiarg:nonnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
   }
   {
    \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
   }
 }

% allocate a private variable
\seq_new:N \l__projetmbc_generic_seq

% the internal version of the general purpose macro
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn
 {% #1 = separator
  % #2 = multiargument
  % #3 = code before
  % #4 = code between
  % #5 = code after

  % a group allows nesting
  \group_begin:
  % split the multiargument into parts
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % execute the <code before>
  #3
  % deliver the items, with the chosen material between them
  \seq_use:Nn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #4 }
  % execute the <code after>
  #5
  % end the group started at the beginning
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn { no }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% separator: ,; before: empty; between: \\, after: empty
\newcommand{\fboxstack}[2][4em]{% #1=width, #2=items
  \fbox{\parbox{#1}{%
    \makemultiargument*{,}{#2}{}{\\}{}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mylist}{str1,str2,str3}

\fboxstack{\mylist}\qquad\fboxstack[8em]{\mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant suggested by your last questions [How to make a macro like \parbox with a style of spread align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475182/4427) and [Automatically justify text in \parbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475295/4427)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% a general purpose macro for defining other macros
% \makemultiargument* will do a one step expansion of the second argument
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemultiargument}{smmm+mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \projetmbc_multiarg:nonnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
   }
   {
    \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
   }
 }

% allocate a private variable
\seq_new:N \l__projetmbc_generic_seq

% the internal version of the general purpose macro
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn
 {% #1 = separator
  % #2 = multiargument
  % #3 = code before
  % #4 = code between
  % #5 = code after

  % a group allows nesting
  \group_begin:
  % split the multiargument into parts
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % execute the <code before>
  #3
  % deliver the items, with the chosen material between them
  \seq_use:Nn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #4 }
  % execute the <code after>
  #5
  % end the group started at the beginning
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn { no }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% separator: ,; before: empty; between: \\, after: empty
\newcommand{\fboxstack}[2][4em]{% #1=width, #2=items
  \fbox{\parbox{#1}{%
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}%
    \hbadness 10000 % no warning about underfull boxes
    \makemultiargument*{,}{#2}{}{\par}{}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mylist}{test ab,ab cd,de fg}

\fboxstack{\mylist}\qquad\fboxstack[8em]{\mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, many thanks for your continuous support!!

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to an old question, but since all the previous answers use counter-based conditionals, I propose, for the sake of completeness, a solution based on redefining macros.

```tex
\documentclass[varwidth, border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
  \def\mylist{str1,str2,str3}

  \framebox{
    \parbox{4em}{%
      \foreach[remember=\newline as \mynewline (initially \relax)] \x in \mylist {%
        \mynewline\makebox[4em][s]{\x}%
      }%
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the same result can be obtained with classical `\def` & `\gdef`.

```tex
\documentclass[varwidth, border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
  \def\mylist{str1,str2,str3}

  \framebox{
    \parbox{4em}{%
      \def\mynewline{}%
      \foreach \x in \mylist {%
        \mynewline\makebox[4em][s]{\x}%
        \gdef\mynewline{\newline}%
      }%
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

**Note:** the `\gdef` is need here because `\foreach` creates a group. If we want to avoid this we can use the first solution or another loop, like `\xintFor`.