# Unbounded number of arguments - Good practice

Tags: macros

Here is how I do to work with unbounded number of arguments of a macro. Is there a better way to do that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\makeatletter
    \def\backify#1|#2\@nil{%
        \@ifmtarg{#2}{%
            #1%
        }{%
            #1 \\ \backify#2\@nil%
        }%
    }

    \newcommand\vcoord[1]{%
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \backify#1|\@nil %
        \end{pmatrix}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\vcoord{3 | -4 | 0}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are some ready-made solutions in `etoolbox` (look for `\DeclareListParser` and `\forcsvlist`) and of course `expl3`/LaTeX3 has a lot of list parsing/splitting functions going on.

Comment: We the ready-to-use solutions, can I transform one list sperated with one symbol to the same list separated with another ?

Comment: this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/how-do-i-split-a-string/12811 can help you maybe

Comment: It depends on whether you wish to process the arguments successively, e.g., one by one, or simultaneously. Seems you are interested in processing the arguments successively. Nonetheless the discussion [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/118714) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Your macro `\backify`'s first arg is delimited by `|` and its second arg is delimited by `\@nil`.  If a delimited arg is nested in braces entirely, these braces will be stripped off. Your `\vcoord`-macro processes a list of `|`-delimited arguments. With all elements except the last one, brace-stripping can happen only once, while with the last element brace-stripping can happen twice. As it is relied on `\@nil` not being provided by the user, within `\vcoord`  the sequence `|{\@nil}|\@nil` could be attached and instead of checking on the emptiness of `#2` one could check whether `#1`=`\@nil`.

Comment: Your `\vcoord`-macro seems to be just an example. It has nice arguments. You can do it with `#1\\\backify` as long as cases are excluded where `#1` consists of tokens that erroneously "eat" the trailing `\\\backify` and this way terminate the loop prematurely.

Comment: @UlrichDiez You're right but in (La)TeX I'm just a padawan. I think that I will use the egreg solution.

Comment: @projetmbc As a simple provincial, I'm not very familiar with the Star Wars milieu and therefore had to do a google-search on the word "padawan". :-) I think there is no need to explain oneself. ;-) Do whatever you think does fit your needs the best. That's what everyone does and that's the way things are going on StackExchange: One asks questions. From the answers and comments one chooses what one thinks does fit one's needs the best, or one takes the answers and comments as a source of inspiration for cobbling something together on one's own. ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc As on the one hand, you call yourself "Padawan", and, on the other hand, you write that you wish to stick to egreg's solution, I would like to mention that orienting yourself towards egreg's answers is not a bad strategy at all: Studying egreg's answers helps a lot. Every time I visit TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange, I learn from his answers.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Me too I already know egreg and he is like my Obi Wan Kenobi. ;-) Sorry for this geek culture. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose a different way to cope with what you seem to be doing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% a general purpose macro for defining other macros
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemultiargument}{mmmmm}
 {
  \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
 }

% allocate a private variable
\seq_new:N \l__projetmbc_generic_seq

% the internal version of the general purpose macro
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnn
 {% #1 = separator
  % #2 = multiargument
  % #3 = code before
  % #4 = code between
  % #5 = code after

  % a group allows nesting
  \group_begin:
  % split the multiargument into parts
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % execute the <code before>
  #3
  % deliver the items, with the chosen material between them
  \seq_use:Nn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #4 }
  % execute the <code after>
  #5
  % end the group started at the beginning
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% separator: |; before: \begin{pmatrix}; between: \\, after: \end{pmatrix}
\newcommand{\vcoord}[1]{%
  \makemultiargument{|}{#1}{\begin{pmatrix}}{\\}{\end{pmatrix}}%
 }

\begin{document}

$\vcoord{3 | \vcoord{-4 | -3 } | 0}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to add formatting to each entry, with a trailing optional argument (without it the macro is the same as in the previous version).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makemultiargument}{mmmmmo}
 {
  \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__projetmbc_generic_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_multiarg:nnnnnn
 {% #1 = separator
  % #2 = multiargument
  % #3 = code before
  % #4 = code between
  % #5 = code after
  % #6 = ornament to items

  % allow nesting
  \group_begin:
  % split the multiargument
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \tl_if_novalue:nF { #6 }
   {
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l__projetmbc_temp_seq \l__projetmbc_generic_seq
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #6 }
   }
  #3
  \seq_use:Nn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #4 }
  #5
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\vcoord}{m}
 {
  \makemultiargument{|}{#1}{\begin{pmatrix}}{\\}{\end{pmatrix}}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\pboxed}{m}{\boxed{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\vcoord{3 | \vcoord{-4 | -3 } | 0}$

$\makemultiargument{|}{-4 | -3  | 0}{\begin{pmatrix}}{\\}{\end{pmatrix}}[\pboxed{#1}]$

\end{document}
```

Beware that macros in the trailing argument have to be either fully expandable or protected (which is why I defined `\pboxed`; the standard `\boxed` would not fail, but just by chance).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. I have a little question about the meanings of  mmmmm and the nnnnn. What is for you the best place where to learn expl3 features ?

Comment: @projetmbc `texdoc interface3` for the available functions and a bit about naming conventions, `texdoc expl3` for naming conventions and additional information about LaTeX3. There is also `texdoc ltx3info` and others. Or take a look at the available pdfs on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel

Comment: @egreg Is there a way to give a 6th argument that will be a command to apply on each item of the sequence `\seq_use:Nn \l__projetmbc_generic_seq { #4 }` ?

Comment: @projetmbc Added; not too difficult, after all.

Comment: Except for little padawan like me. ;-) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5):

Using `expl3` (which is loaded by `xparse`) you can use the built-in sequence type. The following defines your `\vcoord` using only built-in functions. The result is not expandable. It also adds two macros, `\readsequence` that sets up a sequence variable (unexpandable), and `\usesequence` which expands to the sequence with each sequence element separated by its argument (expandable). You can look at [`interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) for the documentation of the available functions in `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__projetmbc_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \readsequence { +m +m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__projetmbc_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \usesequence { +m }
  {
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__projetmbc_seq { #1 } { #1 } { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \vcoord { m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__projetmbc_seq { | } { #1 }
    \begin { pmatrix }
      \seq_use:Nnnn \l__projetmbc_seq { \\ } { \\ } { \\ }
    \end { pmatrix }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\readsequence{|}{a|b|c|d|e}
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \usesequence{\\}
  \end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
  \vcoord{3|-4|0}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about best practice, but you can simplify the definition somewhat:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\long\def\backify#1|{#1\backify\\}
\def\endbackify#1#2{}

    \newcommand\vcoord[1]{%
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \backify#1|\endbackify|%
        \end{pmatrix}%
    }


\begin{document}

$\vcoord{3 | -4 | 0}$

\end{document}
```