# expl3 - An environment to explain the calculation of an expected value (finite case)

Tags: environments, expl3

I would like to automate the production of the following output (the formatting is not so good but I will do a better one later).

[image]

This picture has been obtained using this code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{r|c|c|c|c|c}[name=tab]
    x_k  & 0      & 1   & 2   & 3    & 4    \\
    \hline
    p_k  & 0.2000 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.05 & 0.15  \\
\end{NiceArray}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[draw = red,
          rounded corners,
          fit = (tab-1-2.north west) (tab-1-2.north east) 
                (tab-2-2.south west) (tab-2-2.south east)] {};
    \node[draw = blue,
          rounded corners,
          fit = (tab-1-4.north west) (tab-1-4.north east) 
                (tab-2-4.south west) (tab-2-4.south east)] {};
    \node[draw = black!60!green,
          rounded corners,
          fit = (tab-1-6.north west) (tab-1-6.north east) 
                (tab-2-6.south west) (tab-2-6.south east)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

$E(X) = \sum_k p_k x_k$

$E(X) = \tcboxmath[colframe = red]%
       {0.2000 \cdot 0}
      + 0.2    \cdot 1
      + \tcboxmath[colframe = blue]%
       {0.4    \cdot 2}
      + 0.05   \cdot 3
      + \tcboxmath[colframe = black!60!green]%
       {0.15   \cdot 4}$

\end{document}
```

I would like to only type the array part of the code.

```
\begin{exvalexpval}
    x_k  & 0      & 1   & 2   & 3    & 4    \\
    \hline
    p_k  & 0.2000 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.05 & 0.15  \\
\end{exvalexpval}
```

The algorithm could be the following one but I do not know how to do that with `expl3`.

1. Store the xk value in a list.
2. Store the pk value in other list.
3. Use the lenght of the lists to build the argument `r|c|c|c|c|c` of `NiceArray`.
4. Use the two lists to build the content after the table.
5. Wich colors ? In practice I think that no more than five colors `red`, `blue`, `black!60!green`, `orange` and `gray` will be really needed. If more colors are needed, just use a cycle of colors.

**Note :** I do not want to calculate the value of the expected value. There will be cases of use with formal values in the table.

Comment: Some hints: see latex3 functions in (sub)package `l3seq`, especially the `\seq_set_split:Nnn` and mapping functions. They are documented in [`interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). And you may also input in csv format and use existing csv-parsing packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% Sources
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475291/6880
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558343/6880
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558185/6880

\newcommand\decoframe[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[draw = #1,
          rounded corners,
          thick,
          fit = (#2.north west) (#2.north east) 
                (#3.south west) (#3.south east)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\decobox[2]{
    \tcboxmath[colframe = #1,
               left = 0mm, right = 0mm, top = 0mm, bottom = 0mm,
               boxsep = 1mm, ,boxrule = 1pt]{#2}
}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Global variables used.
    \seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_colors_seq
    \tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl

    \seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq
    \seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_subseq_seq
    \tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
    \tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl

    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_nbline_int
    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int
    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_decotwo_int

% #1 : line separator
% #2 : cell separator
% #3 : content
    \NewDocumentCommand{\calcexpval}{O{red,blue,orange,gray} m m +m} {
        \tnscalc_calcexpval:nnnn{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    }

% The internal version of the general purpose macro
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \tnscalc_calcexpval:nnnn {
% #1 (option) : colors
% #2 : line separator
% #3 : cell separator
% #4 : content
  
% Colors.
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_colors_seq { , } { #1 }
        
% Split into lines
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq { #2 } { #4 }
        
        \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_nbline_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq }

% Split each line into cells.
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
        \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_x_seq { #3 } \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
        
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
        \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_p_seq { #3 } \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl

% Number of columns (offensive programming)
        \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_x_seq }

        \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int { 2 }

% The table of values                 
        \[%|*{\int_use:N \l_mbc_N_int}{c}
            \begin{NiceArray}{r*{\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int}{|c}}
                x\sb{k} & \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl \\
                \hline
                p\sb{k} & \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
                \CodeAfter  
                \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int {2}
                \bool_while_do:nn { \int_compare_p:nNn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int < \l__tnscalc_numcol_int }{
                    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_colors_seq \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
                    \seq_put_right:NV \l__tnscalc_colors_seq {\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}
                    \decoframe{\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}{1-\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int}{2-\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int}
    
                    \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int {2}
                }
            \end{NiceArray}
        \]
        
% Explain the calculus of the expected value.
        \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int { 1 }
              
        $E(X) = \sum\limits\sb{k=1}^{\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int} p\sb{k} \cdot x\sb{k}$
        
        \par
        
        $E(X) = 
        
        \bool_while_do:nn { \int_compare_p:nNn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int > 0 }{
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_x_seq \l__tnscalc_xval_tl
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_p_seq \l__tnscalc_pval_tl
        
            \bool_if:NTF { \int_compare_p:nNn { \int_eval:n{ \int_mod:nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int 2} } = 1 }  { 
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_colors_seq \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
            \seq_put_right:NV \l__tnscalc_colors_seq {\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}
    
            \decobox{\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}{\l__tnscalc_xval_tl \cdot \l__tnscalc_pval_tl}
        } {
            \l__tnscalc_xval_tl \cdot \l__tnscalc_pval_tl
        }
    
            \bool_if:NTF { \int_compare_p:nNn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int = 1 }  { } { + }

            \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int {1}
            \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int {-1}
        }
        $
    } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

Let's try...

\calcexpval{\\}{&}{
    0      & 1   & 2   & 3    & 4    \\
    0.2000 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.05 & 0.15
}

With the default cycle of colors.

\calcexpval{\\}{&}{
    0      & 1   \\
    0.2000 & 0.2
}

With an odd number of columns and the cycle of colors \verb#blue,gray#.

\calcexpval[blue,gray]{\\}{&}{
    0      & 1   & 2   \\
    0.2000 & 0.2 & 0.4
}

With a single( ? ) column and the cycle of colors \verb#black#..

\calcexpval[black]{\\}{&}{
    0      \\
    0.2000
}

%With the short cycle of colors \verb#blue,red#..

\calcexpval[blue,red]{\\}{&}{
    0      & 1   & 2   & 3    & 4    & 1   & 2   & 3    \\
    0.2000 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.05
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is my first go at the code. I am trying to learn LaTeX3, so I shamelessly admit this is a bit a bait so that someone will *bleah* over it and will try to teach me the correct way...

In this first code (this is just my second snippet in `expl3`), there are no color boxes, etc --- it's just a proof of concept. I have to think a bit more about how to do it. There is also no check whatsoever --- put lists with different lengths here and anything can happen.

```latex
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_mbc_listx_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mbc_listp_seq
\NewDocumentCommand\ShowExpectedCalculation{mmmmm} % x, p, index, list x, list p
{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mbc_listx_seq {,} {#4}
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mbc_listp_seq {,} {#5}
    \int_zero_new:N \l_mbc_N_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_mbc_N_int { \seq_count:N \l_mbc_listx_seq }
    %
    % generate the first table
    %
    \[
    \begin{array}{l|*{\int_use:N \l_mbc_N_int}{c}}
        #1\sb{#3} & \seq_use:Nn \l_mbc_listx_seq { & } \\
        #2\sb{#3} & \seq_use:Nn \l_mbc_listp_seq { & } \\
    \end{array}
    \]
    %
    % generate the generic formula. Use \sb here, `_` in ExplSyntaxOn is a normal letter
    %
    \[
        E(x) = \sum\sb{#3=1}\sp{\int_use:N \l_mbc_N_int} #1\sb{#3}#2\sb{#3}
    \]
    %
    % generate the expansion of the sum in a new sequence list
    %
    \int_zero_new:N \l_cnt_int
    \int_incr:N \l_cnt_int
    \fp_zero_new:N \l_expected_fb
    \seq_clear_new:N \l_tmp_seq
    \int_do_while:nn {\l_cnt_int <= \int_use:N \l_mbc_N_int}
    {
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l_tmp_seq {
            {\seq_item:Nn  \l_mbc_listx_seq {\int_use:N \l_cnt_int}}
            \cdot
            {\seq_item:Nn  \l_mbc_listp_seq {\int_use:N \l_cnt_int}}
        }
        \fp_add:Nn \l_expected_fb {
            \seq_item:Nn  \l_mbc_listx_seq {\int_use:N \l_cnt_int}
            *
            \seq_item:Nn  \l_mbc_listp_seq {\int_use:N \l_cnt_int}
         }
        \int_incr:N \l_cnt_int
    }

    \[
        E(x) = \seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {+} = \fp_use:N \l_expected_fb
    \]
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\ShowExpectedCalculation{x}{p}{k}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}{0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.05, 0.15}

\ShowExpectedCalculation{L}{p}{i}{-1, 0, 1}{0.2, 0.4, 0.4}

\ShowExpectedCalculation{Y}{p}{j+z}{3}{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is probably a better way to map together a couple (or three, that I need in case of color) sequences, but I have not yet read it ;-)...

Comment: Great ! For the colors it seems that Tikz offers cycle functiion but I do not yet use it.

Comment: I have to mix your solution with others that I have to obtain the table like syntax.

Comment: The macro `\sb` has to be used each time with to print an underscore in an `expl3` macro. Am I right ?

Comment: The problem is that `expl3` redefine the underscore as a normal character, so you have to use `\sb` for the math subscript. I used also `\sp` for symmetry, not really needed.

Comment: @projetmbc I'd use expansion to insert  a subscript char (``\char_generate:nn { `\_ } { 8 }``), but that's a matter of personal preference

Comment: @Rmano I have posted one solution.