# expl3 - Left pop a list - How to split a temp var coming from a \seq_pop_left?

Tags: lists, expl3

I would like to split a multiline content regarding `\\` and then split each item regarding `.` .

Then I would like to iterate over each list in parallel such as to print their items together suchas to print for example `a1i b2ii c3iii`.

I am trying to pop from the left the first list to read it item by item but this doesn't work...
I would like to see `a-ok-b-ok-c` but I just see `a . b . c` ... An expansion problem I think...

This question is a simplifcation of the real case of use indicated in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557952/expl3-an-environment-to-explain-the-calculation-of-an-expected-value-finite-c).

```
\documentclass{article}

% Source : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475291/6880

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%\seq_new:N \l__pmbc_seq % Not useful here.

% #1 : line separator
% #2 : cell separator
% #3 : content
    \NewDocumentCommand{\splittab}{m m +m}{
        \tnscalc_splittab:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3}
    }

% The internal version of the general purpose macro
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \tnscalc_splittab:nnn{
        % #1 : line separator
        % #2 : cell separator
        % #3 : content

        % A group allows nesting
        \group_begin:
            % Split into parts
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__pmbc_seq { #1 } { #3 }

            %\int_zero_new:N \l_mbc_N_int  % Not useful here.
            %\int_set:Nn \l_mbc_N_int { \seq_count:N \l__pmbc_seq }  % Not useful here.
            %
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__pmbc_seq {\l__temp}
            
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__pmbc_subseq { #2 } { \l__temp }
            
            \seq_use:Nn \l__pmbc_subseq { -ok- }
        \group_end:
    } 
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \splittab{\\}{.}{ a . b . c \\ 1 . 2 . 3 \\ i . ii . ii }
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\seq_pop_left: NN` should not have a space.

Comment: Oups ! Thanks for pointing that. There is now another problem dealing surely with expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use proper naming.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Source : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475291/6880

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_subseq_seq
\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_splittab_int
\tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_temp_tl

% #1 : line separator
% #2 : cell separator
% #3 : content
\NewDocumentCommand{\splittab}{m m +m}
 {
  \tnscalc_splittab:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3}
 }

% The internal version of the general purpose macro
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tnscalc_splittab:nnn
 {
  % #1 : line separator
  % #2 : cell separator
  % #3 : content
  % A group allows nesting
  \group_begin:
  % Split into parts
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq { #1 } { #3 }

  \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_splittab_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq } % why?
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq \l__tnscalc_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_subseq_seq { #2 } \l__tnscalc_temp_tl
  \seq_use:Nn \l__tnscalc_subseq_seq { -ok- }
  \group_end:
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\splittab{\\}{.}{ a . b . c \\ 1 . 2 . 3 \\ i . ii . ii }

\end{document}
```

You need to split the contents of the token list where the popped item has been stored, so the right function is `\seq_set_split:NnV`.

It's not clear what's the function of the integer variable.

Comment: For the integer, it is used in the post for the real use case. I forgot to remove it in my code (I will do it now)... Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: For the integer variable I will use it to print something and I would like to use it to pop all the elements by poping N times. Is there a best way to pop all the elements ?

Comment: @projetmbc I guess you want `\seq_map_inline:Nn`

Comment: Indeed I will pop the three lists splitted regarding \\ in parallel and then apply a formatting to the poped elements of each line (the number of `&` is unbounded)...

Comment: I have post a small question about the way I use to iterate on my lists herer : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558347/expl-3-is-there-a-good-way-to-pop-and-act-on-all-the-items-of-a-list .