# expl 3 - Is there a good way to pop and act on all the items of a list?

Tags: lists, expl3, loops

Here is how I act on a tabular like content. I would like to know if there is a better way than using `\bool_while_do` like I do ?

The following MWE is the starting point to do what I was asked for in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557952/6880) (the hardest has been done from my point of view).

```
\documentclass{article}

% Sources
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475291/6880
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558343/6880

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_subseq_seq
\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_nbline_int
\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
\tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl

% #1 : line separator
% #2 : cell separator
% #3 : content
\NewDocumentCommand{\splittab}{m m +m}
 {
  \tnscalc_splittab:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3}
 }

% The internal version of the general purpose macro
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tnscalc_splittab:nnn
 {
  % #1 : line separator
  % #2 : cell separator
  % #3 : content
  % A group allows nesting
  \group_begin:
  % Split into parts
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq { #1 } { #3 }

  \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_nbline_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq } % why?
  
  % First column
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_x_seq { #2 } \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl

  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_splittab_seq \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_p_seq { #2 } \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
  
  \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_x_seq }
  
  % Pop the column by column.
  \bool_while_do:nn { \int_compare_p:nNn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int > 0 }{
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_x_seq \l__tnscalc_x_tl
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_p_seq \l__tnscalc_y_tl
  
    (\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int :: \l__tnscalc_x_tl ; \l__tnscalc_y_tl)
  
    \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int {-1}
  }
  \group_end:
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\splittab{\\}{&}{ a & b & c \\ 1 & 2 & 3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky if you don't have a fixed number of items to process, but doable of course.  The implementation of `\tnscalc_splittab:nnn` below will split the sequence twice, at the first then at the second delimiter, then restructure it as:

```latex
\__tnscalc_item:nw {a}{b}{c}\q_recursion_tail
\__tnscalc_item:nw {1}{2}{3}\q_recursion_tail
\__tnscalc_item:nw {\q_nil }\q_stop \q_recursion_stop
```

Then every `\__tnscalc_item:nw` will collect the item after it, except for the end marker `\q_nil`, and pass the collected items to `\__tnscalc_do:n`.  After a few expansion steps you will have:

```latex
\__tnscalc_do:n {{a}{1}}
\__tnscalc_item:nw {b}{c}\q_recursion_tail
\__tnscalc_item:nw {2}{3}\q_recursion_tail
\__tnscalc_item:nw {\q_nil }\q_stop \q_recursion_stop
```

with the first batch of items removed.  After a few more, you'll have:

```latex
\__tnscalc_do:n {{a}{1}} % already executed
\__tnscalc_do:n {{b}{2}}
\__tnscalc_item:nw {c}\q_recursion_tail
\__tnscalc_item:nw {3}\q_recursion_tail
\__tnscalc_item:nw {\q_nil }\q_stop \q_recursion_stop
```

then the last batch will be used and the `\q_recursion_tail` markers will signal the end of the list and you'll have:

```latex
\__tnscalc_do:n {{a}{1}} % already executed
\__tnscalc_do:n {{b}{2}} % already executed
\__tnscalc_do:n {{c}{3}} % already executed
```

Since the number of items is variable, each column is passed to `\__tnscalc_do:n` with all items braced, so in `\__tnscalc_do:n` you have to figure out what is the number of items (`\tl_count:n {#1}` might help) and process them accordingly.  You can also map to every item in the column using `\tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { <code with ##1> }`.

The mapping makes sure that `\__tnscalc_do:n` receives always the same number of items.  Any incomplete column is ignored.

To get the output from your code you can define `\__tnscalc_do:n` as:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_do:n #1
  {
    (\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int :: \use_i:nn #1 ; \use_ii:nn #1 )
    \int_decr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
  }
```

(note that the usage of `\use_i:nn` and `\use_ii:nn` assumes that there are only two `\\`-separated items; if the number is different you can't use those two anymore!)

> [image]

Changing the definition of `\__tnscalc_do:n` to:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_do:n #1
  {
    Column~\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int :~
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#1}
      { (##1) }
    \par
    \int_decr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
  }
```

produces, for the same input:

> [image]

You can make the definition of `\__tnscalc_do:n` an argument to `\splittab`, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \splittab { m m +m }
  { \tnscalc_splittab:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
% Variables
\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq
\tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_items_tl
% Main function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tnscalc_splittab:nnn
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_clear:N \l__tnscalc_items_tl
      \int_set_eq:NN \l__tnscalc_numcol_int \c_max_int
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq {#1} {#3}
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq
        {
          \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq {#2} {##1}
          \__tnscalc_seq_set_map:NNn \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq
            \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq { {####1} }
          \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
            {
              \int_min:nn { \l__tnscalc_numcol_int }
                { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq }
            }
          \tl_put_right:Nx \l__tnscalc_items_tl
            {
              \exp_not:N \__tnscalc_item:nw
              \seq_use:Nn \l__tnscalc_tmp_seq { }
              \exp_not:N \q_recursion_tail
            }
        }
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__tnscalc_items_tl
        { \__tnscalc_item:nw { \q_nil } \q_stop }
      \tl_use:N \l__tnscalc_items_tl \q_recursion_stop
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_item:nw
  { \__tnscalc_iterate_collect:nnw { } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_iterate_collect:nnw #1 #2
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#2}
    \quark_if_nil:nTF {#2}
      { \__tnscalc_iterate_collect_end:nw {#1} }
      { \__tnscalc_iterate_collect_more:nw { #1{#2} } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_iterate_collect_more:nw #1 #2
    \__tnscalc_item:nw #3 \q_stop
  { \__tnscalc_iterate_collect:nnw {#1} #3 \__tnscalc_item:nw #2 \q_stop }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_iterate_collect_end:nw #1
    \__tnscalc_item:nw #2 \q_stop
  {
    \__tnscalc_do:n {#1}
    \__tnscalc_item:nw #2 \__tnscalc_item:nw { \q_nil } \q_stop
  }
% Compatibility for older expl3
\cs_if_exist:NTF \seq_set_map_x:NNn
  { \cs_new_eq:NN \__tnscalc_seq_set_map:NNn \seq_set_map:NNn } % newer expl3
  {
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_seq_set_map:NNn #1 #2 #3
      { \seq_set_map:NNn #1 #2 { \exp_not:n {#3} } } % older expl3
  }
%
% In this macro, #1 will have as many items as
% there are \\-separated items in your list.
%
% You can iterate over those items with \tl_map_inline:nn
% or you can have some other macro process them.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tnscalc_do:n #1
  {
    (\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int :: \use_i:nn #1 ; \use_ii:nn #1 )
    \int_decr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
    % Column~\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int :~
    % \tl_map_inline:nn {#1}
    %   { (##1) }
    % \par
    % \int_decr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\splittab{\\}{&}{ a & b & c \\ 1 & 2 & 3 }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.