# Freezing compilation coming from a macro when `\tcbuselibrary{minted}` is used

Tags: macros, minted, latex3, compilation-error

In the following code the use of `\tcbuselibrary{minted}` breaks the compilation and if I comment the use of `\redoit{}` the compilation succeeds.

Why ? How do I fix this ?

Here is the message I have with an infinite loop.

```
...
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '4.31'
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '4.31'
)))/Users/projetmbc/anaconda3/bin/pygmentize

No file x-storebis-x.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
```

If I type CTRL+C, I can see :

```
! Interruption.
\tnscalc_calcexpval:nnnn ...tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
                                                  \CodeAfter \int_add:Nn \l_...
l.150 \redoit
             {}
```

The code of `\redoit` is the following one where `\lastcontent` contains a table like content (`\\` for new lines and `&` for new cells).

```
\newcommand\redoit{
    \expandafter\calcexpval\expanded{{\lastcontent}}
}
```

Here is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbuselibrary{minted} % This breaks the compilation.

% Sources
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475291/6880
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558343/6880
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558185/6880

\newcommand\decoframe[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[draw = #1,
          rounded corners,
          line width=1pt,
          fit = (#2.north west) (#2.north east) 
                (#3.south west) (#3.south east)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\decobox[2]{
    \tcboxmath[colframe = #1,
               left = 0mm, right = 0mm, top = 0mm, bottom = 0mm,
               boxsep = 1mm, boxrule = 1pt]{#2}
}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Global variables used.
    \seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_colors_seq
    \tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl

    \seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq
    \seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_subseq_seq
    \tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
    \tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl

    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_nbline_int
    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int
    \int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_decotwo_int

% #1 : line separator
% #2 : cell separator
% #3 : content
    \NewDocumentCommand{\calcexpval}{O{red,blue,orange,gray} +m} {
        \gdef\lastcontent{#2}
        \tnscalc_calcexpval:nnnn{#1}{\\}{&}{#2}
    }

% The internal version of the general purpose macro
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \tnscalc_calcexpval:nnnn {
% #1 (option) : colors
% #2 : line separator
% #3 : cell separator
% #4 : content
  
% Colors.
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_colors_seq { , } { #1 }
        
% Split into lines
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq { #2 } { #4 }
        \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_nbline_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq }

% Split each line into cells.
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
        \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_x_seq { #3 } \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
        
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
        \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_p_seq { #3 } \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl

% Number of columns (offensive programming)
        \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_x_seq }
        \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int { 2 }

% The table of values                 
        \[
        \setlength\arraycolsep{.75em}
        \begin{NiceArray}{r*{\l__tnscalc_numcol_int}{|c}}
            x\sb{k} & \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl \\
            \hline
            p\sb{k} & \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
            \CodeAfter  
            \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int {2}
            \bool_while_do:nn 
                { \int_compare_p:nNn { \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int } < { \l__tnscalc_numcol_int } }{
                \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_colors_seq \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
                \seq_put_right:NV \l__tnscalc_colors_seq {\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}
                \decoframe{\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}{1-\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int}{2-\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int}
    
                \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int {2}
            }
        \end{NiceArray}
        \]
        
% Explain the calculus of the expected value.
        \int_incr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int
 
        $E(X) = \sum\limits\sb{k=1}^{\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int} p\sb{k} \cdot x\sb{k}$
        
        \par
        
        $E(X) = 
        \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__tnscalc_x_seq {
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_p_seq \l__tnscalc_pval_tl
            \int_if_odd:nTF
                { \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int }
                { 
                    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_colors_seq \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
                    \seq_put_right:NV \l__tnscalc_colors_seq {\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}
            
                    \decobox{\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}{##2 \cdot \l__tnscalc_pval_tl}
                }
                { ##2 \cdot \l__tnscalc_pval_tl }
    
            \int_compare:nNnT { ##1 } < { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_x_seq } { + }
            \int_incr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int
        }
        $
    } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\redoit{
    \expandafter\calcexpval\expanded{{\lastcontent}}
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

Let's try...

\calcexpval{
    0      & 1   & 2   & 3    & 4    & 5   & 6   \\
    0.2000 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0.1 & 0.2
}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\redoit{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have noticed that this is the use of `\redoit` and `\tcbuselibrary{minted}` that makes the compilation going into an infinite loop

Comment: I wrote it. Here is its code : `\newcommand\redoit{\expandafter\calcexpval\expanded{{\lastcontent}}}` .

Comment: So the problem now is not that of the minted library, but that of your macro. I can't help you here, I only use LaTeX to create geometry exercise polycops with TikZ and I don't master macro creation at all. Change the title of your question related to this error and add the macro tag so that the pros of TeX, LaTeX and LaTeX3 will be interested in your problem. Have a nice evening.

Comment: Well, using `\expanded` when the argument contains tokens such as ``\\`` is ***very*** risky. In the sense that it will definitely break.

Comment: @egreg Is there a way to save my argument safely such as to reuse it at another place ? Or do I have to use another approach ? Concretly I want to define my table of values and prints it in a place, and then explains my calculus in another place with the possibility to print or not another time the table decorated as it is the case in the code of the OP.

Comment: @egreg `\expandafter\calcexpval\expandafter{\lastcontent}` works. Why `expanded` breaks things ?

Comment: @projetmbc For the same reason as `\edef\test{\bfseries}` fails. Well, ``\\`` may work in `\expanded`, but there are many other commands which don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `expl3`, avoid `\gdef` and `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbuselibrary{minted} % This breaks the compilation.

% Sources
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475291/6880
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558343/6880
%   * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558185/6880

\newcommand\decoframe[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[draw = #1,
          rounded corners,
          line width=1pt,
          fit = (#2.north west) (#2.north east) 
                (#3.south west) (#3.south east)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\decobox[2]{%
    \tcboxmath[colframe = #1,
               left = 0mm, right = 0mm, top = 0mm, bottom = 0mm,
               boxsep = 1mm, boxrule = 1pt]{#2}%
}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Global variables used.
\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_colors_seq
\tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \g_tnscalc_content_tl

\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tnscalc_subseq_seq
\tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl

\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_nbline_int
\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int
\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int
\int_new:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_decotwo_int

% #1 : line separator
% #2 : cell separator
% #3 : content
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcexpval}{O{red,blue,orange,gray} +m}
  {
    \tnscalc_calcexpval:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tnscalc_calcexpval:nn
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_tnscalc_content_tl {#2}
    \__tnscalc_calcexpval:nnnn{#1}{\\}{&}{#2}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tnscalc_calcexpval:nn { nV }

% The internal version of the general purpose macro
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tnscalc_calcexpval:nnnn
  {
    % #1 (option) : colors
    % #2 : line separator
    % #3 : cell separator
    % #4 : content
  
    % Colors.
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_colors_seq { , } { #1 }

    % Split into lines
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq { #2 } { #4 }
    \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_nbline_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq }

    % Split each line into cells.
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_x_seq { #3 } \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl
        
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_calcexpval_seq \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__tnscalc_p_seq { #3 } \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl

    % Number of columns (offensive programming)
    \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_x_seq }
    \int_set:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int { 2 }

    % The table of values                 
    \[
    \setlength\arraycolsep{.75em}
    \begin{NiceArray}{r*{\l__tnscalc_numcol_int}{|c}}
        x\sb{k} & \l__tnscalc_xline_temp_tl \\
        \hline
        p\sb{k} & \l__tnscalc_pline_temp_tl
        \CodeAfter  
        \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_int {2}
        \bool_while_do:nn 
          {
            \int_compare_p:nNn { \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int } < { \l__tnscalc_numcol_int }
          }
          {
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_colors_seq \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
            \seq_put_right:NV \l__tnscalc_colors_seq {\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}
            \decoframe{\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}
                {1-\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int}
                {2-\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int}
    
            \int_add:Nn \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int {2}
          }
    \end{NiceArray}
    \]

    % Explain the calculus of the expected value.
    \int_incr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int
    $E(X) = \sum\limits\sb{k=1}^{\int_use:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_int} p\sb{k} \cdot x\sb{k}$
    \par
    $E(X) = 
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__tnscalc_x_seq
      {
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_p_seq \l__tnscalc_pval_tl
        \int_if_odd:nTF { \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int }
          { 
            \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tnscalc_colors_seq \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
            \seq_put_right:NV \l__tnscalc_colors_seq \l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl
            
            \decobox{\l__tnscalc_actual_color_temp_tl}{##2 \cdot \l__tnscalc_pval_tl}
          }
          { ##2 \cdot \l__tnscalc_pval_tl }
    
        \int_compare:nNnT { ##1 } < { \seq_count:N \l__tnscalc_x_seq } { + }
        \int_incr:N \l__tnscalc_numcol_deco_int
      }
    $
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\redoit}{O{red,blue,orange,gray}}
  {
    \tnscalc_calcexpval:nV {#1} \g_tnscalc_content_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

Let's try...

\calcexpval{
    0      & 1   & 2   & 3    & 4    & 5   & 6   \\
    0.2000 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0.1 & 0.2
}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\redoit

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\redoit[gray,orange,red,blue]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's pettier like that!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\expandafter\calcexpval\expandafter{\lastcontent}` seems to work.