# How to turn off automatic text justification in a \parbox?

Tags: parbox, justification

The following code produces the result in the picture below.

How can I avoid text justification at the line that starts with "Create Challenge"? I have tried to apply what is suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475295/automatically-justify-text-in-parbox) but it does not work in my case.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
\centerline{\textbf{Protocol $\Pi_{GR}$}}
\bigbreak
Parties $\mathcal{P}$ = \{$\mathcal{P}_{1}$,..., $\mathcal{P}_{n}$\} interact with each other and with $\mathcal{F}_{SmartContract}$, $\mathcal{F}_{RandomCommittee}$, $\mathcal{F}_{Voting}$ as follows:
\bigbreak
\textbf{Create Challenge}: On input $(\textsc{Create-Challenge}, sender, value)$ send $(\textsc{Create-Challenge}, sender, value)$ to $\mathcal{F}_{SmartContract}$.
\newline
\textbf{Accept Challenge}:
\newline
    }
}
\caption{Protocol $\Pi_{GR}$.} \label{fig:sm}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Result of the code]

If I apply `\parbox{\textwidth}{\raggedright` it is closer to what I want, but it does not split the mathematical expression between two lines.

[image: Result of applying suggestion]

Comment: Try with  `\parbox{\textwidth}{\raggedright`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is closer to what I want, but it does not split the mathematical expression between two lines (I edited the question with the result). I suppose this is another problem however. I had a similar problem with long citations in the past.

Comment: @Lorenzo: So you want it split, possible between `CREATE-` and `CHALLENGE`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `\allowbreak` without success. As far I understand, you need to add this command manually (or by using a macro) anyway.

Comment: If you want the three `$\mathcal{F}...` expressions at the end of the second (input) line to all go to a new line, you can replace the input spacebar spaces between them by `~` to "tie" them together.  This, together with `\raggedright` gives the result I think you want.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton, the problem I was talking about was related to `$(\textsc{Create-Challenge}, sender, value)$`, that I have now have replaced with `(\textsc{Create-Challenge}, \textit{sender}, \textit{value})`. It still does not split it between different lines, but since it is not anymore a mathematical expression using `$`, I suppose it should work.